# the round() function does not work in CSPARQL

Tags: function, stream, sparql, rdf

I am trying to do stream processing with [CSPARQL](http://streamreasoning.org/resources/c-sparql). I want to use `round()` function. The query runs well with SPARQL, but when I run it in CSPARQL, the `round()` function did not work.

The SPARQL code:

```
SELECT ?roundlat  (COUNT(?x) AS ?counter)
WHERE {
    ?x pos:location ?point.
    ?point pos:lat ?lat;
        pos:long ?long. 
    BIND (fn:round(?lat * 1000) AS ?roundlat) 
    BIND (fn:round(?long * 1000) AS ?roundlong) 
    } 
GROUP BY ?roundlat ?roundlong 
HAVING (?counter > 10)
```

The CSPARQL code is almost the same with above, except the `FROM <my stream>`

```
SELECT ?roundlat  (COUNT(?x) AS ?counter)
FROM <MY STREAM>
WHERE ...
```

The running result of CSPARQL shows the total count result of `?x`, as if it is not grouped at all, and the `?roundlat` value is blank. It could not execute `fn:round()` as SPARQL did. Could anybody tell me how can I use `round()` function in CSPARQL? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try using the SPARQL 1.1 keyword: ROUND(...)

Comment: Thank you very much. The ROUND() runs very well in SPARQL, but I want to use it in C-SPARQL, the Continuous SPARQL that is a advanced version of SPARQL, with the function of stream processing. But it could not work in C-SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

It has been found out that C-SPARQL supports very limited functions comparing to SPARQL. It does not support math functions such as ROUND().